# Find a space whose fundamental group is $\mathbb Z/2 × \mathbb Z$

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups, free-product

> Find a space whose fundamental group is
>
> i) $\mathbb Z/2 × \mathbb Z$
>
> ii) $\mathbb Z/2 ∗ \mathbb Z$

Here, $\mathbb Z$ is the set for integers. And $*$ is the free product defined as $F(G \amalg H)/\cong,$ $\times$ is the Cartesian product where $A \times B$ has pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a\in A, b \in B$

---

My thoughts:

The first one could be $\pi(X \times S^1$) where $X$ has a fundamental group of $\mathbb Z/2$, but I don't think I know how to derive a space with such fundamental group.  Can you give me an example of such space, and how to derive such space like that (with the $/2$)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your idea is fine (to get point i))! Do you know Van Kampen or covering space theory? I have written a rough outline below on how you may proceed, just let me know if you need more help...

Comment: Note that for $\mathbb{Z}_2 *\mathbb{Z}$ you need the same space $X$ but now you take the wedge sum $X\vee S^1$ instead of the Cartesian product which can be derived from Van Kampen (under suitable conditions on $X$, e.g. $X$ locally contractible).

Comment: @freakish oh my, I didn't want to spoil OP with this:) Anyway, we still have to wait and see if OP is familiar with Van Kampen.

Comment: @noctusraid Hi, first thanks for your reply! I barely knew the Van Kampen theorem, I didn't do any problems & didn't know it well enough to see how it applies here. Could you please write more details about "To derive this you could look..." part? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Liz You're welcome. Where did you see Van Kampen? In your lecture? Or in a book? Usually, indipendently of where you look it up, shortly after Van Kampen, some examples are made in order to illustrate how it is applied. Maybe you should first take a look at how one computes the fd group of the torus using Van Kampen. The computation for the real projective space is almost the same.

Comment: @noctusraid Sure, will try it out! So will the real projective space also works for part 2)? like define X = real projective space, and part 2 is just the wedge sum X∨$S^1$  ?

Comment: @Liz Great! Yes, that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat too long for a comment, but not an answer yet:

Here is a starting hint: The $2$-dimensional real projective space $$\mathbb{R}P^2:=S^2/(-x \sim x)$$ has fundamental group $$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2.$$ To derive this you could look at a unit square $[0,1]^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, use the right identifications on the boundary and apply Van Kampen.

Alternatively, you could use covering space theory and a short exact sequence argument. I'll elaborate the answer if needed.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't know of a nice space with the fundamental group you want, you can always build one!  For example, with $\mathbb{Z}_2  =\langle a:a^2 = 1\rangle$, one begins with $S^1$ and attaches a $D^2$ via a degree two map $S^1 = \partial D^2 \rightarrow S^1$.  (The resulting space happens to be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$).  But this allows one to construct examples with $\pi_1$ any cylic group.  A generalization of this allows one to construct examples with $\pi_1$ any group whatsoever.

Comment: @noctusraid Could you elaborate more on how to derive its fundamental group with Van Kampen?